# get files from failed boot drive ubuntu 16

Tags: boot, hard-drive, data-recovery

Im crossing my fingers that someone can help me out. I have a dell server that I use as a desktop. I have a 2tb boot drive and three addition 2tb drives in a raid 0. The boot drive has been acting funny the last couple weeks in that I need to run a manual fsck every time I boot or reboot. I bought a new 2tb drive last week thinking I'd just replace the drive this weekend. I booted the server, and the hard drive wasn't found. I tried to boot from a usb and I can see the raid but cannot access it at all (no permissions), and I still can't see the failed boot drive. I unfortunately have work on the boot drive that is unfinished and not backed up yet... uhh, flog me. Id really like to figure out how to access whatever files maybe remaining on this drive and hopefully recover whatever is remains of my project. Any ideas?

EDIT: per the discussion in the comments, an Ubuntu based solution was not found, this is a hardware issue. If I find a solution I'll edit this post for the benefit of others in need.

Comment: Did you verify the health of the drive using `gnome-disks`, `smartctl` or another like tool (these read the electronics of the drive to give health info, not the disk data itself).  Even on a 'dead' drive, if the electronics are still valid you can usually get clues (does BIOS recognize device?)  If you can't access the partitions, the data is gone without a lot of off-topic work (where reading the health is the first step for any drive in my opinion, regularly during its life so you can predict failure - what SMART is for). You may be able to replace the bad component from another drive..

Comment: I have not tried that yet in apart because bios does not recognize the device. I'm looking into ways around this issue. Any ideas related to trouble shooting a boot drive that isn't recognized by bios?

Comment: Thats not entirely true, it is recognized but has an error. I'm rebooting now to get the exact error.

Comment: sas discovery error 0x00000002, accompanied by the "click of death"... is there any hope?

Comment: I don't remember (*I usually eject drives before failure on my PEs' thru monitoring health of drives...*) - but regardless this is now off-topic here as is dell/hardware specific and not related to Ubuntu at all.

Comment: Shoot. I was hoping for some slick Ubuntu solution to get me out of this hole. I appreciate your thoughts. I'll proceed accordingly.

Comment: I would use Ubuntu to explore - starting with aforementioned tools ran from a 'live' (or install media).   If using Ubuntu, and asking about Ubuntu detail we can provide help - but questions about your hardware error messages are off-topic was my point.  I suggested checking drive health (using Ubuntu) in my first comment; you opted to go a different route...   (*If you have drive issues, you never run from an installed OS as you want to avoid making any potential problems on the drive worse - using a 'live' ubuntu will not touch drive, leaving any life left for recovery first...*)